# Change isolation level - hibernate.connection.isolation does not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using spring boot and would like to change the default isolation level to `READ_UNCOMMITTED`.

I searched and found the property `hibernate.connection.isolation`, but I tried it and it did not work.

My configuration is this:

```
private Properties additionalJpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.isolation", String.valueOf(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED));

        return properties;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(this.packages);
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(this.additionalJpaProperties());
        return em;
    }
```

How do I change the isolation level using spring boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs the solution. The only solution I found was this:

Extend the `HibernateJpaDialect` class and implement the `beginTransaction` method to set transact isolation. It looks like this:

```
@Service
public class CustomHibernateJpaDialect extends HibernateJpaDialect {

    @Override
    public Object beginTransaction(final EntityManager entityManager,
            final TransactionDefinition definition) throws PersistenceException,
            SQLException, TransactionException {

        Session session = getSession(entityManager);

        if (definition.getTimeout() != TransactionDefinition.TIMEOUT_DEFAULT) {
            session.getTransaction().setTimeout(definition.getTimeout());
        }

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        session.doWork(new Work() {
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction(connection, definition);
                connection.setTransactionIsolation(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
            }
        });

        return prepareTransaction(entityManager, definition.isReadOnly(), definition.getName());
    }

}
```

And in the configuration of the entityManagerFactory it is necessary to set the dialect created:

```
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            DataSource dataSource,
            CustomHibernateJpaDialect customHibernateJpaDialect) throws SQLException {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaDialect(customHibernateJpaDialect);

        return em;
    }
```